# Create trigger that ensures there is one and only one NON-NULL in a set of column and reuse it for other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I know how to create a trigger that checks if a group of columns has one and only one NON NULL  for one table but i would like to reuse the code because i will have some other tables with the same requirements. Any recommendations? I was thinking of maybe a trigger that passes it's name of the columns to be checked  and table name  to a stored procedure and the function does the rest, but i'm not sure on how to implement it.

EDIT: i tried

```
DROP tAble if exists t;
create table t(

a integer,
b integer,
c integer,
CONSTRAINT enforce_only1FK CHECK ((a <> NULL)::integer +(b <> NULL)::integer+(c <>NULL)::integer  = 1)
);
INSERT into t VALUES (4,NULL,6);
```

it should not allow the insert but it does... what am i doing wrong?

EDIT 2 : interesting... it works if i write

```
DROP tAble if exists t;
create table t(

a integer,
b integer,
c integer,
CONSTRAINT enforce_only1FK CHECK ((a NOT NULL)::integer +(b NOT NULL)::integer+(c NOT NULL)::integer  = 1)
);
INSERT into t VALUES (4,NULL,6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a trigger that checks if a group of columns has one and only one NON
>   NULL for one table

This would be a case for a table-level check constraint rather than a trigger.
Example with the constraint on the first 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
 a int, 
 b int,
 c int,
 d text,
 CHECK ((a is not null and b is null and c is null)
  OR (a is null and b is not null and c is null)
  OR (a is null and b is null and c is not null))
);
```

or in more elaborate form with a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_notnull(variadic arr int[]) returns int as
$$
 select sum(case when $1[i] is null then 0 else 1 end)::int
     from generate_subscripts($1,1) a(i);
$$ language sql immutable;

CREATE TABLE tablename (
 a int, 
 b int,
 c int,
 d text,
 CHECK (count_notnull(a,b,c)=1)
);
```

This second form looks better when many columns are involved in the constraint but it requires them to be all of the same type.

Comment: small optimization: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.null_count(VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql AS $function$SELECT sum(CASE WHEN v IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::int FROM unnest($1) g(v)$function$

Comment: well then i guess this approach would be very good for the FK checking i am trying to do. Last time i checked FKs are generaly of same type when it comes to inheritance.It's actually great because this FK check is the alternative to joined inheritance table that i want to avoid ( i'm to lazy practially check if joined inheritance will affect the performance of my app so i'll just trade some memory for some safety when it comes to performance).

Comment: i like this one(with pavel stehule s contribution) marginally more than @cloadoaldoneto s solution. Too bad i can't accept two answers

Answer (score 1):

That is not a case for a trigger. Just a check constraint:

```
create table t (
    a integer,
    b text,
    c boolean
    check ((
        (a is not null)::integer
        + (b is not null)::integer
        + (c is not null)::integer
        ) = 1)
);]
```

In instead of checking every possible combination just use the boolean cast to integer and sum the results.

```
insert into t (a, b, c) values
(1, 'a', true);
ERROR:  new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "t_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, a, t).

insert into t (a, b, c) values
(null, 'b', false);
ERROR:  new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "t_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, b, f).

insert into t (a, b, c) values
(2, null, null);
INSERT 0 1

insert into t (a, b, c) values
(null, null, null);
ERROR:  new row for relation "t" violates check constraint "t_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null).
```

Comment: but your check constraint assures that there is one null field i wanted a one non-null field. the conditions should be negated i think. More like : (a <> null)::integer
        + (b <> null)::integer
        + (c <>null)::integer

Comment: @meldor Ok sorry. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how much following trick is clean or ugly, but it works:

```
postgres=# create table foo1(a int);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# create unique index on foo1((1)) where a is null;
CREATE INDEX

postgres=# insert into foo1 values(null);
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# insert into foo1 values(null);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo1_expr_idx"
DETAIL:  Key ((1))=(1) already exists.
postgres=#
```

Notes to triggers: PL/pgSQL is not good language for writing generic triggers. You should to use PLperl or PLpython. Next - triggers is not good tool for ensuring uniqueness - you should be very careful there - there is a risk of race conditions or high locking - it require some experience do this work well. So better method is using indexes where is it possible.

Comment: how does having a trigger that enforces the fact that out of a group of  say 4 columns only one is NON-NULL, the other being nulls,  increase the risk of high locking?

Comment: I don't understand your request well - when you don't request dependency between rows, then trigger doesn't increase locking. But you can use simply CHECK instead generic trigger: CHECK (CASE WHEN a1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN a2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN a3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END <= 1)

Comment: That would be an elegant solution for the "pivoted" case - only one row per table is allowed to have a value in a column.